# doing a substitution until certain condition is true

Tags: perl

I'm trying to edit a text using Perl. I need to make a substitution but the substitution cannot be applied once an specific word is found in the text. So, imagine I want to substitute all the "hello" forms by "goodbye", but the substitution cannot be applied once the word "foo" is found.

I tried to do this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
$/ = undef;
my $filename = shift;
open F, $filename or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
while(<F>) {
do {s/hello/goodbay/} until (m{foo});
print;
}
close F;
```

But, as a result, only the first "hello" of my text is changed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: When "foo" is found do you want to stop replacing just on that line and start replacing on the next line, or do you want to stop replacing in the file completely?

Comment: I want to stop replacing in the file completely

Comment: Why do you set `$/` to `undef`?

Comment: Because I wanted to prevent perl from reading line by line. But I could erase it, if it is needed for my "stop replacing" purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to think what would be the most efficient. It should be one of the following:

```
s{^(.*?)(foo|\z)}{
   my $s = $1;
   $s =~ s{hello}{goodbay}g;
   $s.$2
}se;
print;
```

or (same as above, but requires 5.14+)

```
s{^(.*?)(foo|\z)}{ s{hello}{goodbay}gr . $2 }se;
print;
```

or

```
my $pos = /foo/ ? $-[0] : length;
my $s = substr($_, 0, $pos, '');
$s =~ s{hello}{goodbay}g;
print($s);
print;
```

Both work even if `foo` isn't present.

This solution uses less memory:

```
# Assumes foo will always be present
# (though it could be expanded to handle that
# Assumes foo isn't a regex pattern.
local $/ = "foo";
$_ = <$fh>;
chomp;
s{hello}{goodbay}g;
print;

print $/;

local $/;
print <$fh>;
```

Comment: Do `(foo|$)` to cover the case where `foo` isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

If the substrings you work on (the hello and foo of your example) are single words, a easy way would probably be to replace `$/ = undef;` with `$/ = " ";`. Currently you slurp in the whole file at once, meaning the while loop gets executed at most once. 
That is because there is only one "line" in the whole input after you told perl that there are no line separators.
If you use a space as input separator, it will loop over the input word by word and hopefully work as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag variable:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $filename = shift;
open F, $filename or die "Usa: $0 FILENAME\n";
my $replace=1;
while(<F>) {
    $replace = 0 if m{foo};
    s/hello/goodbye/g if $replace;
    print;
}
close F;
```

This stops at the line containing the end pattern. It will be slightly more complicated if you want to substitute up to just before the match.

Comment: this won't replace the first 2 hellos on a line like this "hello there hello foo hello" but it should.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses the `${^PREMATCH]` and related variables introduced in Perl 5.10.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo_found;
while (my $line = <>) {
  if (!$foo_found) {
    if ($line =~ m/foo/ip) {
      # only replace hellos in the part before foo
      ${^PREMATCH} =~ s/hello/goodbye/g;
      $line = "${^PREMATCH}${^MATCH}${^POSTMATCH}";
      $foo_found ++;
    } else {
      $line =~ s/hello/goodbye/ig;
    }
  }
  print $line;
}
```

Given the following input:

```
hello cruel world
hello baseball
hello mudda, hello fadda
foo
The rest of the hellos should stay
Last hello
```

I get the following output

```
goodbye cruel world
goodbye baseball
goodbye mudda, goodbye fadda
foo
The rest of the hellos should stay
Last hello
```

If you don't have 5.10 you can use `` $` `` and related variables but they come with a performance hit. See `perldoc perlvar` for details.

Comment: or you use use `/^(.*?)(foo)(.*)/` and `"$1$2$3"` and have a solution that works with any version.